# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'CORE'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT X.CORE.Jobs.CreationDate AS 'Date Created', X.CORE.JobControlSheets.PrintJobName AS 'Batch Id', X.CORE.Jobs.JobId AS 'Job Name',
X.CORE.JobToJob.JobToJobId AS 'Sub- Job Name', X.CORE.JobControlSheets.DespatchMethod AS 'Postal Class', X.CORE.JobControlSheets.EnvelopeCode AS 'Envelope Code',
Y.[PrintStatus],Y.[PrintDate],Y.[DespatchDate], Y.[EnclosedDate],Y.[DocsetCount], Y.[FileName]
From 
(SELECT        CORE.Jobs.CreationDate AS 'Date Created', CORE.JobControlSheets.PrintJobName AS 'Batch Id', CORE.Jobs.JobId AS 'Job Name', 
                         CORE.JobToJob.JobToJobId AS 'Sub- Job Name', CORE.JobControlSheets.DespatchMethod AS 'Postal Class', 
                         CORE.JobControlSheets.EnvelopeCode AS 'Envelope Code', CORE.JobControlSheets.PrintJobName
FROM            CORE.Jobs INNER JOIN
                         CORE.JobControlSheets ON CORE.Jobs.JobId = CORE.JobControlSheets.JobId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         CORE.JobToJob ON CORE.Jobs.JobId = CORE.JobToJob.SourceJobId) AS X
                         INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [PrintStatus],[PrintDate],[DespatchDate],[EnclosedDate],[DocsetCount], [FileName]
FROM 
(SELECT distinct Jc.JobID, 
case when EXists (SELECT distinct jobid FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_000_Outstanding JO WHERE JO.jobid=Jc.JobID) 
then 'Inprogress' else 'Complte' end as [PrintStatus],Jb.[FileName] as [FileName]
FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions Jc 
INNER JOIN [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_001_Jobs Jb on Jb.ID=Jc.JobID) as A
left JOIN 
(SELECT JobID,[Timestamp]   as [PrintDate] FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions jc WHERE 
[Service] = 'PRINT' and JobStatus = 'Printed') as B on A.JobID=B.JobID 
left JOIN 
(
SELECT jobid,sum(Packs) as [DocsetCount],max(DespTimestamp)   as [DespatchDate] FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions GROUP BY JobID) 
as C on B.JobID=C.JobID
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT JobID,Timestamp   as [EnclosedDate] FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions WHERE JobStatus = 'Processed')
  D on C.JobID=D.JobID) AS Y on Y.FileName=X.FileName
```

Comment: `AS X` aliases the select to `X` so you have `X.F` available where `F` is the name of a field in that `SELECT`.  `X.CORE.something.whatever` is meaningless.

Comment: After this amendment invalid column name error occur.

Answer (score 0):

You made mistakes with the column alias in the first sub query. Also use **table alias** when joining the tables, it will be better readability and easy to use.

You can simply retrieve the column names with out column alias inside the first sub query and later you can add the alias name in the outer SELECT.

Can you try the following query:

```
SELECT X.CreationDate AS 'Date Created', X.PrintJobName AS 'Batch Id', X.JobId AS 'Job Name', X.JobToJobId AS 'Sub- Job Name', 
       X.DespatchMethod AS 'Postal Class', X.EnvelopeCode AS 'Envelope Code', 
       Y.[PrintStatus], Y.[PrintDate], Y.[DespatchDate], Y.[EnclosedDate], Y.[DocsetCount], Y.[FileName]
FROM (
    SELECT [CJ].CreationDate, [CJC].PrintJobName, [CJ].JobId, [CJJ].JobToJobId, [CJC].DespatchMethod, [CJC].EnvelopeCode
    FROM CORE.Jobs [CJ]
    INNER JOIN CORE.JobControlSheets [CJC] ON [CJ].JobId = [CJC].JobId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CORE.JobToJob [CJJ] ON [CJ].JobId = [CJJ].SourceJobId
    ) AS X
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [PrintStatus], [PrintDate], [DespatchDate], [EnclosedDate], [DocsetCount], [FileName]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Jc.JobID, CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (
                        SELECT DISTINCT jobid
                        FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_000_Outstanding JO
                        WHERE JO.jobid = Jc.JobID
                        )
                    THEN 'Inprogress'
                ELSE 'Complte'
                END AS [PrintStatus], Jb.[FileName] AS [FileName]
        FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions Jc
        INNER JOIN [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_001_Jobs Jb ON Jb.ID = Jc.JobID
        ) AS A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT JobID, [Timestamp] AS [PrintDate]
        FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions jc
        WHERE [Service] = 'PRINT'
            AND JobStatus = 'Printed'
        ) AS B ON A.JobID = B.JobID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT jobid, sum(Packs) AS [DocsetCount], max(DespTimestamp) AS [DespatchDate]
        FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions
        GROUP BY JobID
        ) AS C ON B.JobID = C.JobID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT JobID, TIMESTAMP AS [EnclosedDate]
        FROM [MI_ProdMI].dbo.JOB_Tbl_002_Completions
        WHERE JobStatus = 'Processed'
        ) D ON C.JobID = D.JobID
    ) AS Y ON Y.FileName = X.FileName
```